# How can I insert a space between two fields in a formula?

Tags: email, formula, picklist, formula-field, multi-select

There´s a lot of work to do with this formula, but to start with:

> IF ( INCLUDES ( Email_Failed_Formats__c , "firstname.lastname" ),
>   "FirstName.LastName; ",null ) & 
>   IF ( INCLUDES (
>   Email_Failed_Formats__c , "firstinitial.lastname" ),
>   "LEFT(FirstName__c, 1).LastName; ",null ) & 
>  IF ( INCLUDES (
>   Email_Failed_Formats__c , "firstname.lastinitial" ),
>   "FirstName.LEFT(LastName__c, 1); ",null ) & 
>  IF ( INCLUDES (
>   Email_Failed_Formats__c , "firstnamelastinitial" ),
>   "FirstNameLEFT(LastName__c, 1); ",null ) & 
>  IF ( INCLUDES (
>   Email_Failed_Formats__c , "firstinitiallastname" ),
>   "LEFT(FirstName__c, 1)LastName; ",null ) & 
>  IF ( INCLUDES (
>   Email_Failed_Formats__c , "firstnamelastname" ), "FirstNameLastName;
>   ",null ) & 
>  IF ( INCLUDES ( Email_Failed_Formats__c ,
>   "firstname_lastname" ), "FirstName_LastName; ",null ) & 
>  IF ( INCLUDES
>   ( Email_Failed_Formats__c , "lastnamefirstinitial" ),
>   "LastName.LEFT(FirstName__c, 1); ",null ) & 
>  IF ( INCLUDES (
>   Email_Failed_Formats__c , "lastname.firstinitial" ),
>   "LastName.LEFT(FirstName__c, 1); ",null ) & 
>  IF ( INCLUDES (
>   Email_Failed_Formats__c , "firstname" ), "FirstName; ",null ) & 
>  IF (
>   INCLUDES ( Email_Failed_Formats__c , "lastname" ), "LastName; ",null )

It isn´t returning the name of the contact in any of these formats, despite the fields being correct.

I'm hoping to show the name of the contact in a format that depends on what is chosen in the multi-select picklist.

For instance, if "firstname.lastname" is chosen in the multi-select picklist, that should result in "John.Smith" appearing in the formula text field.
If "firstinitial.lastname" is chosen, that should result in "J.Smith". And so on...

Part of the problem seems to be the spacing between the"FirstName" and "LastName" fields, but the method suggested below results in a syntax error (Found 'LastName').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here´s what I got to work, in the end, thanks to @cropredy, @Adrian Larson and @crmprogdev.

```
IF ( INCLUDES (  Email_Failed_Formats__c , "firstname.lastname" ), FirstName & '.' & LastName, null) & 
IF ( INCLUDES (  Email_Failed_Formats__c , "firstnamelastname" ), FirstName & '' & LastName, null ) & 
IF ( INCLUDES (  Email_Failed_Formats__c , "firstname_lastname" ), FirstName & '_' & LastName, null ) &  
IF ( INCLUDES (  Email_Failed_Formats__c , "firstname" ), FirstName, null ) & 
IF ( INCLUDES (  Email_Failed_Formats__c , "lastname" ), LastName, null ) &
IF ( INCLUDES ( Email_Failed_Formats__c , "lastnamefirstinitial" ), LastName & '' & LEFT(FirstName, 1), null ) &
IF ( INCLUDES ( Email_Failed_Formats__c , "lastname.firstinitial" ), LastName & '.' & LEFT(FirstName, 1), null ) &
IF ( INCLUDES ( Email_Failed_Formats__c , "firstinitial.lastname" ), LEFT(FirstName, 1) & '.' & LastName, null ) & 
IF ( INCLUDES ( Email_Failed_Formats__c , "firstname.lastinitial" ), FirstName & '.' & LEFT(LastName, 1), null ) & 
IF ( INCLUDES ( Email_Failed_Formats__c , "firstnamelastinitial" ), FirstName & '' & LEFT(LastName, 1), null ) & 
IF ( INCLUDES ( Email_Failed_Formats__c , "firstinitiallastname" ), LEFT(FirstName, 1) & '' & LastName, null )
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the syntax you're looking for would be:

```
IF ( INCLUDES ( Email_Failed_Formats__c , "firstname.lastname" ), FirstName+"."+LastName; ,null )
```

Comment: Thanks, but this results in a syntax error (Found 'LastName')...any ideas?

Comment: Concatenation operator is `&`, not `+`.

Comment: I tried & as well: IF ( INCLUDES ( Email_Failed_Formats__c , "firstname.lastname" ), FirstName &' . '& LastName; ,null

Comment: @ESil `IF ( INCLUDES ( Email_Failed_Formats‌​__c , "firstname.lastname" ), FirstName & '.' & LastName, null)`

Comment: Thanks @AdrianLarson and cropredy. Can you tell I don't write a lot of workflow rules? ;) Thanks for helping him get to the finish line guys. :)